# Oracle SQL sysdate alternatives?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sysdate

I'm using a software that allows me to run Oracle SQL queries but only a stripped kind. Functions like `REPLACE`, `SUBSTR`, `KEEP`, `DENSE_RANK`, etc. do not work. Just today I also found out that `SYSDATE` doesn't work and I need to find an alternative to it.

I found [this article](https://blogs.oracle.com/ecmarch/entry/be_aware_of_the_difference) and one of the comments pointed out the difference between `SYSDATE` and `CURRENT_DATE` and thought I could use `CURRENT_DATE` but it turns out that the function depends on the session timezone and not on the OS time which could give me a different result. The user also presented solutions like

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'Canada/Eastern';
```

But that doesn't work as well. Are there other alternatives you guys are aware of that I could try?

Comment: It sounds like most Oracle functions do not work with this tool.  Assuming that you are stuck using this particular tool, any reason you just can't type the dates in whatever format the DB session requires?

Comment: The only functions that return the "current date and time" are `sysdate`,  `current_date`, `current_timestamp` and `systimestamp` if none of them works (either because of time zones or because that stupid tool doesn't allow them) you are out luck I guess.

Comment: Further to @a_horse_with_no_name, you are SoL and woill have to add or subtract time from each date you pull back with `current_timestamp`

Comment: Basically I need to create a report that gets records from last week. I can do it with this tool by asking for the `start_date` and `end_date` before running the report but ideally the report should just compute for the dates so no user input is needed. I guess I'm out of luck then since I couldn't make the other functions work. Oh well. Thanks for the input guys!